# Not working DLE 10.6 + PHP7 in check_module() where call preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, regex, php-7, preg-replace-callback

I transfered DLE 10.6 to PHP 7 and I saw a blank page. During debugging I found out that if I remove [not-aviable=smth]smth[/not-aviable] from main.tpl website starts working. Ok, I found in templates.class.php method check_module:

```
function check_module($matches) {
    global $dle_module;

    $regex = '/\[(aviable|available|not-aviable|not-available)=(.+?)\]((?>(?R)|.)*?)\[\/\1\]/is';

    if (is_array($matches)) {

        $aviable = $matches[2];
        $block = $matches[3];

        if ($matches[1] == "aviable" OR $matches[1] == "available") $action = true; else $action = false;

        $aviable = explode( '|', $aviable );

        if( $action ) {

            if( ! (in_array( $dle_module, $aviable )) and ($aviable[0] != "global") ) $matches = '';
            else $matches = $block;

        } else {

            if( (in_array( $dle_module, $aviable )) ) $matches = '';
            else $matches = $block;
        }       

    }

    return preg_replace_callback($regex, array( &$this, 'check_module'), $matches);
}
```

When i removed "not-aviable: from $regex website starts workinig.
php.ini contains pcre.backtrack_limit = 1000000

Comment: And what is middle *smth*?

Comment: html code or text. aviable contains the same and working perfect [aviable=smth]smth[/aviable]

Comment: By asking *What is...* I mean it exactly. Please put a real world sample in your question.

Comment: [not-aviable=sportivnie-podborki-filmov|faq]   {content} [/not-aviable]

Comment: [not-aviable=showfull] 
<div style="margin-top:15px;">
  <center>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter" data-counter=""></div>
  </center>
</div>  
[/not-aviable]